# How to change the Database connection mid code in OctoberCMS / Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I am trying to create one system that would work for multiple customers, each with their own database but using the same online system.

The summery is, when a user is logged in I would only select the database of his company and would only see data on his database.

if this way is not recommend, Give me your feedback.

Comment: What database would hold the `users` data? As in the data with individual user info and login credentials?

Comment: https://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections take a look at this

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Comment: @thisiskelvin Yes I will create a master database containing all the users and the names of the database they belong to

Comment: @JasperHelmich Thanks a ton man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Config` facade to change the connection. You will need to ensure that models that use a common database (i.e. user authentication) have their database connections set explicitly so that the dynamic changes in the configuration don't affect those models.

Here's an example of how you would accomplish this.

In your custom plugin's Plugin.php file:

```
use Config;
use Backend\Models\User;
use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function register()
    {
        User::extend(function($model) {
            $model->setConnection('my_default_connection');
        });

        Config::set('database.default', 'this_companies_connection');
    }
}
```

Comment: @luckeTowers is their a way that allows me to set the connection name and it's parameters on the fly? 
cuz using the `Config::set('database.default', 'this_companies_connection');` assumes that I have the connection details in the config.php that contains the connection parameters for all my databases, but in reality I only save the databases name in the record of the company that each user belongsTo

Comment: @AhmedAlbarody yes, see https://octobercms.com/forum/post/multiple-database-connections-in-octobercms#post-7347. You just need to do that before you use the newly defined connection anywhere.